# Hyphen + Space "shortcut" to lists in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Most of you are probably familiar with this: After writing "-" and pressing space on a new line, MS Word automatically starts a new list  - sometimes.

I have found this particular feature quite handy and should like to use it more reliably.

At the moment, some times it works, other times it doesn't. So far, I failed at finding a pattern.

Does anybody know how to make it work when it decides not to?